# Loading audio file to template causes ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer (Django, Python)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, terminal

I am making an audio player webapp using Django. The audio files are uploaded by admin via a model that adds the file to my Media directory. Then in my template the audio files are displayed with an individual audio player.

```
{% for song in songs %}
   <audio class="player" controls>
      <source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/wav">
   </audio>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Now, the website works as intended. The audio players all become visible and are working correctly. However in my terminal, every time the page is loaded I get errors of this type (depending on how many audio files that are to be displayed, if there only is one file i get this for example):

```
[13/Dec/2019 12:03:31] "GET /media/ap/song.wav HTTP/1.1" 200 1626112
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60242)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/oscarjonsson/python-virtual-environments/django_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/oscarjonsson/python-virtual-environments/django_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

What could be the cause of this? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code that might be helpful:**

```html
{% for song in songs %}
   <audio class="player" controls>
      <source src="{% if song.audio_file %}{{ song.audio_file.url }} {% endif %}" type="audio/wav">
   </audio>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer would be more helpful if you can add some details/comments on how/why your given code works.